# How can I implement minimized logo in header on page scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I need help in implementing minimized logo and also display post title after the page is scrolled for some vertical distance. like on this url  **[Minimized Logo and show post title](https://www.littlethings.com/no-talent-artwork/?utm_medium=google)**

Comment: @Aloïs de La Comble Am actually designing a blog using wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

```js
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );

function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 300,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
```

```css
/* =Template
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#wrapper{width:100%;margin:0 auto}#main{background-color:#fff;padding-top:150px}.container{width:80%;margin:0 auto;padding:0 30px}section{padding:60px 0}section h1{font-weight:700;margin-bottom:10px}section p{margin-bottom:30px}section p:last-child{margin-bottom:0}section.color{background-color:#3cb5f9;color:#fff}

/* =Header
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
header{width:100%;height:150px;overflow:hidden;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;background-color:#0683c9;-webkit-transition:height .3s;-moz-transition:height .3s;-ms-transition:height .3s;-o-transition:height .3s;transition:height .3s}header h1#logo{display:inline-block;height:150px;line-height:150px;float:left;font-family:Oswald,sans-serif;font-size:60px;color:#fff;font-weight:400;-webkit-transition:all .3s;-moz-transition:all .3s;-ms-transition:all .3s;-o-transition:all .3s;transition:all .3s}header nav{display:inline-block;float:right}header nav a{line-height:150px;margin-left:20px;color:#9fdbfc;font-weight:700;font-size:18px;-webkit-transition:all .3s;-moz-transition:all .3s;-ms-transition:all .3s;-o-transition:all .3s;transition:all .3s}header nav a:hover{color:#fff}header.smaller{height:75px}header.smaller h1#logo{width:150px;height:75px;line-height:75px;font-size:30px}header.smaller nav a{line-height:75px}


/* =Media Queries
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  /* =Header
  -------------------------------------------------------------- */
  header h1#logo,header nav{display:block;float:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto}header h1#logo{height:100px;line-height:100px}header nav{height:50px}header nav a{line-height:50px;margin:0 10px}header.smaller{height:75px}header.smaller h1#logo{height:40px;line-height:40px;font-size:30px}header.smaller nav{height:35px}header.smaller nav a{line-height:35px}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <a href="">Ipsum</a>
            <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->

<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Header Resize On Scroll with Animations</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>                
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div><!-- #main -->



</div><!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Would you please check my above snippet?

Comment: i had checked on that one but code seems all too much yet i wanted a much simpler option. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it.

Checkout this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ah68cv7L/5/

Hide `overflow` in your header and add a `max-height` and then use `translateY` to translate the container `nav-head` and show one of the two div `min-head` and `max-head`

`min-head` is hidden by default because it overflowed the header max height so, only `max-head` div is shown by default.

Then you do `translate` on the `nav-head` div to show the overflowed `min-head` div.

```
header {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

`_top = $('article p').offset().top;`

Here we are storing the original offset top of paragraph before any scroll occurs.

In the java script we are using scroll event of jquery on the `container` element.

for more information on scroll event click [here](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

```
$('.container').on('scroll', function(e) {

  if (!scrolled 
      && ((_top - $('article').children('p').offset().top <= 20)
      || (($('article').children('p').offset().top -_top) + ($('article').height())) > 0)) {

            $('header .nav-head').css('transform', 'translateY(-55px)');
            scrolled = true;

  } else if (($('article').children('p').offset().top - _top == 0) 
                    || (($('article').children('p').offset().top -_top) + ($('article').height()))<0) {

            $('header .nav-head').css('transform', 'translateY(0px)');
                    scrolled = false;
  }
});
```

Here we are checking the offset on scroll with the before scroll offset and if the element is scrolled more than `20px` which is the height of the title of the paragraph.

we are adding the css class `transform:translateY(-55px)` to the container div.

**SNIPPET**

```js
_top = $('article p').offset().top;
scrolled = false;
$('.container').on('scroll', function(e) {

  if (!scrolled 
      && ((_top - $('article').children('p').offset().top <= 20)
      || (($('article').children('p').offset().top -_top) + ($('article').height())) > 0)) {
      
            $('header .nav-head').css('transform', 'translateY(-55px)');
            scrolled = true;
            
  } else if (($('article').children('p').offset().top - _top == 0) 
       || (($('article').children('p').offset().top -_top) + ($('article').height()))<0) {
        
            $('header .nav-head').css('transform', 'translateY(0px)');
        scrolled = false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:600px;
}
.max-head {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.mini-head-title{
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
}

.logo{
  padding:5px;
}

header {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-head {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

article {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color:#eee;
}

.head-title {
  height: 20px;
}
.dont-minimize{
    background-color:red;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<header>
  <div class="nav-head">
    <div class="max-head">
      <img class = "logo" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="min-head">
      <img class="logo" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">
      <span class="mini-head-title">Some Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<article>
  <div class="head-title">Some Title</div>
  <p>
    Every time I go to a home store, I fall in love with the wall hangings, paintings, and wooden boxes that have cute sayings on them, like “live, laugh, love” and “family first.” I always want to buy them for my apartment and for my friends’ apartments,
    but when I look at the price tag, I’m dumbfounded! How could something so simple cost so much? If you’re anything like me and always find yourself lusting over these lovely pieces of artwork, you’re going to love this simple DIY. Instead of spending
    a bunch of money on cute prints and clever sayings, make your own! All you need for this project are a few simple art supplies and a picture frame. Follow along with the instructions below to learn how to make this ridiculously easy artwork at home!Every
    time I go to a home store, I fall in love with the wall hangings, paintings, and wooden boxes that have cute sayings on them, like “live, laugh, love” and “family first.” I always want to buy them for my apartment and for my friends’ apartments, but
    when I look at the price tag, I’m dumbfounded! How could something so simple cost so much? If you’re anything like me and always find yourself lusting over these lovely pieces of artwork, you’re going to love this simple DIY. Instead of spending a
    bunch of money on cute prints and clever sayings, make your own! All you need for this project are a few simple art supplies and a picture frame. Follow along with
    
    Every time I go to a home store, I fall in love with the wall hangings, paintings, and wooden boxes that have cute sayings on them, like “live, laugh, love” and “family first.” I always want to buy them for my apartment and for my friends’ apartments,
    but when I look at the price tag, I’m dumbfounded! How could something so simple cost so much? If you’re anything like me and always find yourself lusting over these lovely pieces of artwork, you’re going to love this simple DIY. Instead of spending
    a bunch of money on cute prints and clever sayings, make your own! All you need for this project are a few simple art supplies and a picture frame. Follow along with the instructions below to learn how to make this ridiculously easy artwork at home!Every
    time I go to a home store, I fall in love with the wall hangings, paintings, and wooden boxes that have cute sayings on them, like “live, laugh, love” and “family first.” I always want to buy them for my apartment and for my friends’ apartments, but
    when I look at the price tag, I’m dumbfounded! How could something so simple cost so much? If you’re anything like me and always find yourself lusting over these lovely pieces of artwork, you’re going to love this simple DIY. Instead of spending a
    bunch of money on cute prints and clever sayings, make your own! All you need for this project are a few simple art supplies and a picture frame. Follow along withEvery time I go to a home store, I fall in love with the wall hangings, paintings, and wooden boxes that have cute sayings on them, like “live, laugh, love” and “family first.” I always want to buy them for my apartment and for my friends’ apartments,
    but when I look at the price tag, I’m dumbfounded! How could something so simple cost so much? If you’re anything like me and always find yourself lusting over these lovely pieces of artwork, you’re going to love this simple DIY. Instead of spending
    a bunch of money on cute prints and clever sayings, make your own! All you need for this project are a few simple art supplies and a picture frame. Follow along with the instructions below to learn how to make this ridiculously easy artwork at home!Every
    time I go to a home store, I fall in love with the wall hangings, paintings, and wooden boxes that have cute sayings on them, like “live, laugh, love” and “family first.” I always want to buy them for my apartment and for my friends’ apartments, but
    when I look at the price tag, I’m dumbfounded! How could something so simple cost so much? If you’re anything like me and always find yourself lusting over these lovely pieces of artwork, you’re going to love this simple DIY. Instead of spending a
    bunch of money on cute prints and clever sayings, make your own! All you need for this project are a few simple art supplies and a picture frame. Follow along withthe instructions below to learn how to make this ridiculously easy artwork at home!Every
    time I go to a home store, I fall in love with the wall hangings, paintings, and wooden boxes that have cute sayings on them, like “live, laugh, love” and “family first.” I always want to buy them for my apartment and for my friends’ apartments, but
    when I look at the price tag, I’m dumbfounded! How could something so simple cost so much? If you’re anything like me and always find yourself lusting over these lovely pieces of artwork, you’re going to love this simple DIY. Instead of spending a
    bunch of money on cute prints and clever sayings, make your own! All you need for this project are a few simple art supplies and a picture frame. Follow along with the instructions below to learn how to make this ridiculously easy artwork at home!
  </p>
</article>

<div class="dont-minimize">
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
  some thing else.. I dont need minified div
</div>
</div>
```